# Entity framework GroupBy, Select min and max

Tags: sql, .net, performance, entity-framework, linq

I need some help with a complex query in EF.

What I am trying to do :

For each user within a list, get a list of first and last event for each day from a table with the following structure:

```
Events table:
int EventId
int UserId
DateTime Time
...other fields

Users table:
int UserId
string Name
...other fields
```

What I am currently doing:

1. getting a list of users that are of interest to me
2. for each user get all events from a month
3. iterate through the events to select the first and last event for each day.

This is quite inefficient and time consuming. What I think I could do is :

Select min and max events from a month, grouped by UserId, grouped by Day, so the end result would look like :

```
EventId  UserId  Time
345       4      9:00:00   18.03.2019  //first event from 18.03
456       4      18:20:00  18.03.2019  //last event from 18.03
465       4      10:40:00  19.03.2019  //first event from 19.03
477       4      19:23:00  19.03.2019  //first event from 19.03
360       9      11:05:00  18.03.2019  //same, for different user
440       9      17:10:00  18.03.2019
466       9      10:57:00  19.03.2019
501       9      20:48:00  19.03.2019
```

I need to do this using entity framework, in .Net

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions:

```
select e.*
from (select e.*,
             row_number() over (partition by userid, convert(date, time) order by time) as seqnum,
             count(*) over (partition by userid, convert(date, time)) as cnt
      from events e
     ) e
where e.seqnum = 1 or e.seqnum = cnt;
```

You can `JOIN` in additional user information if you need it.

You can add a `WHERE` clause if you have a particular list of users.

Comment: I am having trouble translating that to LINQ.
Also, doesn't this query return the first and last event for the whole duration of time, without creating subgroups for each day?

Comment: @RazvanOlariu . . . This answers the question:  "For each user within a list, get a list of first and last event for each day from a table with the following structure:".